# Where should I call the Third Party Rest API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, architecture

I am working on a project where I am utilizing the third party Rest API. I am developing the application in ASP.NET MVC3. I have a dataaccess layer and service layer. Where should I call the third party api. As it itself is a rest API, is it neccessary to write one more service layer around it or should I call directly from the controller of my service layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where should I call the third party api.

In the data access layer. That's what this layer is intended to do => access data from different sources such as files, SQL databases, remote services, ...